# 403 (Forbidden) on axios post. Laravel 5.7

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to perform a post request with axios on a vuejs component and it throws an `403 forbidden` error. This is my javascript code for the post request:

```
createMessage() {
            axios.post('/mensajes/guardar', {
                subject: this.subject,
                username: this.username,
                content: this.editorContent
            })
            .then((res) => {
                this.formProcessed = true
                this.swalMixin('success', '¡Mensaje enviado!')
                setTimeout(() => { window.location = '/mensajes' }, 3000)
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                let errors = err.response.data.errors
                let firstError = Object.keys(errors)[0]
                let message = errors[firstError][0]
                this.swalMixin('error', message)
            })
        }
```

The controller's fuction that handles it:

```
public function store(MessageStoreRequest $request)
    {
        $recipient = User::where('username', $request->username)->firstOrFail();

        $message = Message::create([
            'sender_id' => Auth::id(),
            'recipient_id' => $recipient->id,
            'subject' => $request->title,
            'content' => $request->content,
        ]);

        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'success'
        ], 200);
    }
```

My route group for the message model:

```
Route::prefix('mensajes')->middleware(['auth', 'verified'])->group(function () {
    Route::get('/', 'MessageController@index')->name('message.index');
    Route::get('/ver/{id}', 'MessageController@show')->name('message.show');
    Route::get('/crear', 'MessageController@create')->name('message.create')->middleware('can:create,App\Message');
    Route::post('/guardar', 'MessageController@store')->name('message.store')->middleware('can:create,App\Message');
});
```

I've created a custom request to handle the validation:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class MessageStoreRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'subject' => 'required|min:12',
            'username' => 'required|',
            'content' => 'required|min:37'
        ];
    }

    /**
     *  Custom message for validation
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function messages()
    {
        return [
            'subject.required' => 'El asunto es obligatorio.',
            'subject.min' => 'El asunto debe contener al menos 10 caracteres.',
            'username.required' => 'El destinatario es obligatorio.',
            'content.required' => 'El contenido del mensaje no puede estar vacío.',
            'content.min' => 'El contenido del mensaje debe ser de al menos 30 caracteres.'
        ];
    }

    /**
     *  Filters to be applied to the input.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function filters()
    {
        return [
            'subject' => 'trim',
            'username' => 'trim',
            'content' => 'trim'
        ];
    }
}
```

And there is this policy for the Message model:

```
/**
     * Determine whether the user can create messages.
     *
     * @param  \App\User  $user
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function create(User $user)
    {
        return $user->hasAccess(['create-message']);
    }
```

I can't find the problem. I've been working like this with other models and this is the first one that throws this error.

Comment: I'm guessing it's CSRF related, hope these links help: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/csrf https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-can-i-use-csrf-token-with-axios-post-method

Comment: That's the problem. I've been doing the exact same thing in other VueJS components without the CSRF token. This is the first problem and the other module are working just fine.

Comment: @EnriqueBermúdez maybe headers are the thing, if the others views had csrf token meta, then they didn't fail.

Comment: @nyu.exe The other components (vue components) where i perform this post request have the exact same structure. Something i just noticed is that replacing``MessageStoreRequest`` with ``Request`` from my function turns the error into a 404 not found so it might be the custom request but i can't see the error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Lets change `authorize()` function in your customized request to `return true` instead of `return false`.

This function is used to allow or disallow access based on permisions.

Comment: Dude you are totally right. I forgot that simple thing. Thanks a lot for pointing that out for me!